# How to use random to print integers whose sum is less than or equal to another integer in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of integers and I would like to print all integers whose sum is less than than or equal to a variable.  My sum is 38 below, how do I randomly return the values in the list below where my sum is less than or equal to 15?  I have tried to adapt the function below, but it doesn't work.

```
j=[4,5,6,7,1,3,7,5]
x = 15
 jSum = sum(j)


def decomposition(i):
    while i <= x:
        n = random.randint(j, i)
        yield n
        i -= n
        print i
decomposition(jSum)
```

Comment: You want to generate a range of numbers that don't go beyond a specified max value?

Comment: yeah, but that range has to be in `j`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. You just want to sum up as many integers in the list as possible without going above 38? And, what sort of error are you getting? You need to write your question better.

Comment: That is correct @Pat Jones.  I am not getting an error.

Comment: If you just want a random choice from `j`, then: `random.choice(j)`

Comment: @PatJones Where does the `random` aspect come into that method?

Comment: If the limit is the sum of all the choices, wouldn't the result include all combinations taken one at a time to len(j)-1 at a time?

Comment: random should generate a list where the sum not greater than 38.  i.e. if a userinput is 15 then it would generate a list not greater than 15.

Comment: @GeoffreyWest Any `list` or *all* `lists` with a sum less than the input?

Comment: So if I have a variable of x = 15 and my list sum is 38, I want to return a list whose sum is 15 or less from values in my list.  I wrote my question incorrectly.

Comment: @GeoffreyWest Oh, `1` `list` randomly selected from all the `lists` that have a `sum` less than `15`.

Comment: Yes, well j = [list], make a list from j where the sum is less than 15.

Comment: What happens when you run your solution?

Comment: @wwii, i don't receive an output, errors are not thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a `list` of possible `lists`  with `sums` `< x`. This can be done with two nested `for-loops` and `itertools.combinations`:

```
ops=[list(c) for l in range(1,len(j)) for c in itertools.combinations(j,l) if sum(c) < x]
```

then just `randomly` select one with `random.choice`:

```
random.choice(ops)
```

---

And when I ran this with `j = [4,5,6,7,1,3,7,5]` and `x = 15` the random output I got was:

```
[6, 1, 3]
```

Which works! (`sum` is `< 15` and all elements are in `j`)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for @Joe Iddon

Comment: @GeoffreyWest No problem, happy to help! Try to work on wording your questions more clearly next time though. **:)**